# Inserting a character inside the body of a paragraph

Tags: c#, asp.net

If someone enters a very long title/sentence, the text will stretch across the web page.

Is there a way to break the text so it continues on to the next line?

Using overflow hidden will hide the text.

I think I should be using the wbr tag.

**Should I use the insert(); method for this?**

i.e.

```
string myText = "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111";

myText = myText.Insert(80, "<wbr/>");
```

Not sure how cross browser the wbr tag is also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you should use the zero width space (`&#8203;`) for this rather than `<wbr>`. However, Internet Explorer 6 and earlier are known not to support this (they show an ugly box). So `<wbr>` is probably the safest choice. Except... Internet Explorer 8 in standards mode is known not to support `<wbr>`, so you've got yourself a wonderful conundrum here.

You can read more at [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html).

Do note HBoss' comment in that it's hard to predict where to break, unless you're using a fixed width font like Courier. You should probably heed his advice and break more often than just every 80 characters. (And don't get me started on combining characters.)

As far as ASP.NET is concerned, you can indeed use the `Insert` method for this, but beware when you need to insert more than one: you'' need to do some book keeping (and a `StringBuilder` would also be advised).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to find words surrounded by whitespace/special chars, and surround it with a div/span that has different overflow properties.

If you do use `<wbr>`, be sure to surround the word with `<nobr>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can solve this by splitting the content with breaks since you aren't guaranteed that the break will fit uniformly across browsers. You have variations of font-size, widths, etc.

Normally when I see content that extends too var it simply overlaps over the rest of the page or the designer sets the overflow so that the content can be scrolled. There could potentially be some CSS tricks you could use, but I'm not aware of any.

As an alternative approach, instead of simply inserting a line break every *x number* of characters, you might just insert a space after certain characters, for example, punctuation. This will make sure that the content wraps at some point or another.